# I'm trying to make a score counter for my war card game. I want the game to keep going until the user wants to stop. But the score keeps resetting

Tags: python

```
print("Welcome to the Battle Card Game")
player1 = input("Input Player 1 name:")
player2 = input("Input Player 1 name:")


def game():
    
    import random
    values = {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4, "5": 5, "6": 6, "7": 7, "8": 8, "9": 9, "10": 10, "Jack": 11, "Queen": 12, "King": 13, "Ace": 14}
    p1 = (random.choice(list(values.keys())))
    p2 = (random.choice(list(values.keys())))

    p1_score_counter = 0
    p2_score_counter = 0

    print(player1, "Has a", p1)
    print(player2, "Has a", p2)

    if p1 > p2:
        print(player1, "wins")
        p1_score_counter =+1

    elif p1 < p2:
        print(player2, "wins")
        p2_score_counter =+1

    elif p1 == p2:
        print("It's a Tie!")

    print(player1, "Score is", p1_score_counter)
    print(player2, "Score is", p2_score_counter)
    


while True:
    game()
    if input("Repeat the program? (Y/N)").strip().upper() != 'Y':
        break
    #continues if user wants to
```

```
Welcome to the Battle Card Game
Input Player 1 name:1
Input Player 1 name:2
1 Has a 2
2 Has a 5
2 wins
1 Score is 0
2 Score is 1
Repeat the program? (Y/N)Y
1 Has a 9
2 Has a 2
1 wins
1 Score is 1
2 Score is 0
Repeat the program? (Y/N)
```

Comment: That's because your counters are local to the *game()* function and are set to zero every time that function is called

Comment: @Cobra What do I change? Do I move it to the beginning?

Comment: You could make the score counters inputs to the game function and return those values to the caller. The main game loop would pass the current scores into the `game` function when calling it.

Comment: This is also not an unreasonable use for global variables.